# If match isn't found in while loop, display an error message

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, preg-match, fopen

I'm trying to display a single error message "Match not found", if the match isn't found in the while loop.  At the moment, I know that if I put an "else" statement inside, it'll just display "Match not found" for every line until it reaches the end of the loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <?php
        $filename = "roster.txt";
        $fp = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");

        while(!feof($fp))
        {   $line = fgets($fp);

            if (preg_match('/Navi/',$line)) {
                print "$line<br>";      
            }
        }
        fclose($fp)
    ?>
```

Thanks for any help I may get!

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `match` as `false` before while loop and set it to `true` when match is found.
After while loop check `match` variable .

```
$match = false;
while(!feof($fp))
{   $line = fgets($fp);
$answer = str_replace(":"," ",$line);   
  if ((preg_match("/$lastname/",$line)) && (preg_match("/$id/",$line))) {
      $match = true;
      print "$answer<br>";        
  }
}
if ($match === false) {
    echo 'Match not found';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one was nice and simple!

Answer (score 0):

I'm tired... this might not be the most elegant way to do it but it should work.

```
$x=0;
while(!feof($fp))
{   $line = fgets($fp);
$answer = str_replace(":"," ",$line);   
if ((preg_match("/$lastname/",$line)) && (preg_match("/$id/",$line))) {
print "$answer<br>";    
$x = $x+1;    
}
}
if($x==0) {
echo 'No match found';
}
```

Comment: Conceptually that will work, but you have some syntax errors - `x` should be `$x` since it's not a constant and you need to test for `$x==0` since a single `=` will assign a value of `0`. My preference would be to use a boolean unless you care about how many matches you didn't find.

Comment: Ugh, beginner mistakes. Thanks, edited. That is one of the reasons I figured to do it this way, it would return a value for the number found. No idea if that is necessary or not but either way really wouldn't make a performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a boolean value to track if the value *was* found, and then use that to selectively show a message if it *was not* found:

```
<?php
$filename = "roster.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

// variable to track if any matches are found, initialize to false
$found = false;   
while(!feof($fp)){   
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $answer = str_replace(":"," ",$line);   
    if ((preg_match("/$lastname/",$line)) && (preg_match("/$id/",$line))) {
        print "$answer<br>";

        // when a match is found, set to true
        $found = true;    
    }
}

// If no matches were found, show the error message
if (!$found) print "Match not found";
fclose($fp)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a local variable to keep track of wether the match has been found or not. For example in psuedocode:

```
int match_is_found = 0

loop :
    // do stuff
    if match was found:
        match_is_found = 1

end loop

if match_is_found is 0:
    display error message
```

(Sorry if that's not helpful for PHP - never used it).